# Как создать 404 маршрут?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

У меня есть такие маршруты

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/:id' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Из-за маршрута /:id не сработает NotFound. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов, это все же для роута с id использовать какой-то дополнительный сегмент пути:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/somepath/:id' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Другой вариант, если все же хочется оставить предложенные пути,то можно в компоненте Home проверять валидность :id. Здесь в примере в компоненте Home если :id содержит какое-то  значение и не является числом, возвращается компонет NotFound.

```
const checkIsIdValid = (id) => {
  return isFinite(id);
}

export const Home = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  if (id !== undefined && !checkIsIdValid(id)) {
    return <Notfound />
  }


  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}
```